# Store result of a function in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a function

```
list_all_wpmu_blogs($tmp_limit, $tmp_name_or_url, $tmp_begin_wrap, $tmp_end_wrap, $tmp_order)
```

If i use like this

```
<?php list_all_wpmu_blogs('', '', '', '', 0); ?>
```

It lists all my 500+ blogs like this

```
<a href="http://subdomain.myblog.com">blog1</a>
<a href="http://subdomain.myblog.com">blog2</a>
<a href="http://subdomain.myblog.com">blog3</a>
..........
..........
<a href="http://subdomain.myblog.com">blog500</a>
```

Now i want to store those links in a array instead of output it.

Can anyone help me to store them in a array?

I want array like this.

```
array(blog1,blog2,.....,blog500);
```

### Update:

Here is my full function [list_all_wpmu_blogs() code](http://pastebin.com/fn4niFAa)

Comment: Please post the function `list_all_wpmu_blogs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, if you can't change the function:

```
<?php
ob_start();
list_all_wpmu_blogs('', '', '', '', 0);
$output = ob_get_clean();
$arr = explode("\n", $output);  // change \n to your separator
?>
```

However it is much better if you can make changes to your function and use it like this:

```
<?php 
$blogs = list_all_wpmu_blogs('', '', '', '', 0);
var_dump($blogs);
?>
```

Here is the update for the function: http://pastebin.com/y5CkCuxZ

Answer (score 0):

Without your function its a little hard but...

Instaed of outputing put them into the array:

```
$new_array[] = $myVar;
```

$new_array[] will add the variable to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a function" - it is a function provided by WPMU and what it does is echo all the blogs. I'm not sure about an alternative function (http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list - For performance reasons this function is not recommended.), but I'm sure there is one. Alternatively you can use php's output buffering (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to get it in a string (see Alex' answer), but it might be best to write your own SQL to query the table in the database.

What version of wordpress are you using?

**Edit:**

You can use this query

```
global $wpdb;
$sites = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );
```

Comment: There we go :-) Use the function `get_blog_list()` http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/return-a-list-of-sites-on-the-network/

Comment: That function has been [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list)